# HTML z-index does not work for youtube video

Tags: html, youtube, z-index

I have youtube video on page:

```
<iframe id='youtubeTrailer' width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/0Vsy5KzsieQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

and some poster. I wrote index for img greater than for video. but it's still does not work. How can I fix it?

[image: work]

Comment: Post both your CSS and HTML markup.

Answer (score 2):

That's because flash mostly ignores z-index (unless wmode is set to opaque). You can follow the steps detailed [here](http://maxmorgandesign.com/fix_youtube_iframe_overlay_and_z_index_issues/) to correct it.

What the guide above details is just setting the wmode to transparent by modifying the iframe code.

```
<iframe id='youtubeTrailer' width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/0Vsy5KzsieQ?wmode=transparent" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```